# Electric noise filtering seems not to have any effect over voltage input noise

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-regulator, noise, passive-networks, low-pass

I have designed two PCBs with slave SPI nodes at both. One of the two PCBs is connected to a Raspberry SPI port, it became the master node. This PCB also has a 74HC51 (suggested for i2c and spi lines multiplexing) multiplexer for multiplexing CS signal.

The second PCB will  be connected to this first PCB through flat cable. I know working with wired SPI adds a complexity and limitations, such as SCLK frequency that should be lower.

But now I will talk about power lines on first PCB design and noise filtering, abput something that I can't understand.

At this point of hardware testing, there is no master node connected. No clock signal, no control signal, no data signal at bus lines. There is no other PCB connected.

The fact is that I have connected the 5V power supply to the first PCB. As any other industrial shed there are at least two devices such as "water dispenser machine" and a "drill machine" connected to the same electric net. And when water machine starts to cool water or the drill machine starts to run, an electric noise about 14Mhz appears at Vin. The noise always has the same pattern and frequency. And it only appears when two of this machines are activated.

Part of the circuit works with 5V, the other part works with 3.3V. I use the regulator MCP1825ST-3302E/DB with the capacitors that manufacturer suggests to use with (4.7uF in, 1uF out). I put the osciloscope probe at regulator Vout (3.3V) pin and the noise is also there. So, I thought that noise was coming from the outside of my PCB, from the electric net.

[image: PCB power connections]

I also put the probe at SPI connectors lines, and there also are until 1.3 Vpp noise signal, with the same pattern, and 15Mhz freq but amplitude seems smaller than signal noise at Vin. I think this SPI lines noise could increase when bus communications go on and Raspberry starts operations if those machines are activated for a while or whenever someone wants, even other part of the circuit could be affected by the noise. We saw it at other circuit parts. As the 4.7uF needs a Resistor close to 0 Ohms for being RC pass low filter, I thought that this capacitor works iqual as a low pass filter that obviously is not working for 14Mhz signals. Maybe it was not enough and a 2n order filter could help more than RC or RL one does.

So, here, at lab I connected resistor and inductor to the soldered Cin = 4.7uF of regulator and I configured a Butterworth filter for a f = 15000Hz. I also removed the LED resistor before. I used a filter calculator web page and the values were:

- R = 3 Ohms
- C= 5uF
- L = 0.022mH = 22uH

I choose circuit form 1: [RLC calculator and configurator web page](https://wilaebaelectronica.blogspot.com/2017/01/filtro-pasa-bajos-pasivo-de-2do-orden-rlc.html)

So, even if the filter is not well adjusted and cutoff frequency is bigger, 15Mhz is so far from 15, 20 or 50Khz, and some kind of noise attenuation must be seen. But we don't see absolutely any change. It is the same when the filter was not there.

A little sample of noise pattern (14Mhz were measured):

[image: noise at vout regulator 3.3v]

My questions:

- What can it mean that a filter does not affect to the noise signal that seems to come from the electric network? Even if it is not well adjusted to the desired cutoff freq of 15 Khz, until 14Mhz there is a stretch of margin to at least tickle it, I think. But it seems not to be any filter connected (any kind of attenuation), although filter is there.
- Maybe does it means that noise is not entering through the Vin connector, but, leaving the PCB towards the source? If this could be possible, how can the noise be activated inside the board by any external trigger event (a several meters away machine)? Am I filtering wrong or am I looking at the wrong site?

Comment: For all you know at this point, it's the scope that's introducing the noise.  It's main's powered, and also grounded to the mains, right (eg, it's not a battery powered scope).  What do you see if you look at the board's ground?

Comment: Are C0 and C1 tantalum?

Comment: You're probably assuming that C0 is a perfect capacitor.  If it's electrolytic, it will have a non-zero inductance and resistance, and that can make a big difference.  A lower value non-electrolytic capacitor in parallel with it may make a big difference.

Comment: thanks @Chris Stratton, I have a battery osc. I think it could be usefull for watching this. At the same time I would like to add that when the PCB is connected to Raspberry and the second PCB is also connected, this noise trigger is reseting the SPI slave nodes and there is no osciloscope connected. This gives me a little hint about noise is arriving even it doesn't come from oscilloscope. I still following your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Math, I thought at design moment about this, but typicall applications suggested by manufacturer was using X7R Ceramic, so I use this kind of capacitors. They say: A typical 1 μF X7R 0805 capacitor has an ESR of 50 milli-ohms. Aluminum-electrolytic capacitors are not recommended for low temperature applications for otuput. Larger input capacitors will also help reduce any high-frequency noise on the input and output of the LDO and reduce the effects of any inductance that exists between the input source voltage and the input capacitance of the LDO, for input.

Comment: Thanks @Simon B, you are talking about electrolytic capacitors, but what about if they are not electrolytic ones? As I said, I followed the datasheet instructions and suggestions about input and output capacitors.

Comment: It really all depends on the inductance and resistance (ESR) of the capacitor you chose.  But a small ceramic decoupling capacitor of a few nanofarads might help to reduce high frequency noise.

Comment: Hi @Simon So, do you mean by adding nanofarad capacitor in paralel with 4.7uF at regulator input?

Comment: The problem with this noise is that it is enough effect over the chip reset line for reseting it. This signal is now forced to VDD level for ensuring that chip will always be enabled. The reset noise erases all the previous functionality configuration and puts a 0 con configuration register.

Comment: Yes.  Whether or not it will solve your problem is hard to guess, but to should be easy enough to try.